# How can I change the position of mob limbs?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm in need of changing the position of the Enderman's legs when it is in the sitting pose. I have tried searching the files but I couldn't find them so asking here.

Comment: I assume you mean in a resource pack, right? If you want to do it for a single entity with commands, you could try using an armour stand and retexturing armour.

Comment: No, I don't mean resource pack or armour stands. I need to change the position of limbs of a character. I do know it is possible with armour stands but I need to do it with a mob.

Comment: Also, this has been marked as a duplicate question. Could you leave a link to the question?

Comment: I meant making an armour stand look like a zombie, skeleton, whatever, because that's the only thing that has customisable limb positions. And the duplicate link is right there at the top.

Comment: I am sure there is a way, it is just difficult. As for the question, it is not duplicate, I don't know how you cannot see the difference in this question.

Comment: If you think your question is different, edit it to make clear why. Also yes, it is possible, by exactly the way I told you. You could also remodel a block, but that's even more limited. Proper entity models are simply not implemented in Minecraft yet.